# How to redirect request from one server to another

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have 3 Server.

1. Web server - For End User (Internet)
2. APP Server - For access DB Server (It's in Intranet). (communicate
   between Web server & DB server)
3. DB Server - For Database

I want to rewrite request from the web server to APP server. because APP server access DB Server.

Comment: What have you already tried and how does that not satisfy you?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/create-and-implement-3-tier-architecture-in-Asp-Net/